# How to convert VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a varchar value in BD2 Table like below format

```
121226145503+0530
```

I want to convert this varchar value to time stamp format like below

```
2012/12/26 14:55:03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB2 9.7, you can also use the TO_DATE function:

```
date(to_date(column_with_date,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'))
```

Also, you can use the `TRANSLATE` function

```
select 
   date(translate('DD/MM/YYYY',column-with-the-date,'xyz...'))
from
   table
```

Comment: When I usaed first step like below                                                                           DB2 Database Error: ERROR [22007] [IBM][DB2/HPUX-IA64] SQL0969N  There is no message text corresponding to SQL error "-20448" in the message file on this workstation.  The error was returned from module "SQLRI1DC" with original tokens "121226145503+0530 DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS".  SQLSTATE=22007

Comment: I'm not sure who to poke at here - the answer-er, for providing the 'wrong' date/time parsing string, or the questioner, for not recognizing the formatting differences and adjusting.

Comment: @Lilantha Lakmal 
-20448 "An invalid datetime format was detected; that is, an invalid string representation or value was specified."  As the followup comment suggests, the _answerer_ did not provide the desired format-string, so adjustments are required; see my recent answer for the desired TO_DATE syntax, but then the additional requirement from the OP to get the VARCHAR result.

Comment: @Vinayak Pahalwan
The OP shows 'YYMMDD' as the date portion, and 24hr time implied per 14, thus 'HH24MISS' for the time portion. Presumably, as I can not test, a functional TRANSLATE scalar example [but coded with an _assumed_ '20' as first two digits of YYYY] that can be inside the DATE() is?:
 `translate( /* expression   */ '20Yy/Mm/Dd Hh:Uu:Ss'  
        ,  /* to-str-exp   */ '121226145503+0530'
        ,  /* from-str-exp */ 'YyMmDdHhUuSs+zone'   )`
[though unavailable on db2 for i](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317263/db2-argument-02-of-function-translate-not-valid)

Answer (score 0):

```
with d (cwd) as                                              
 (values( cast( '121226145503+0530' as varchar(20))))        
select cwd as vc_input                                       
 ,  to_date(cwd, 'YYMMDDHH24MISS'      )        as ts_from_vc
 ,  varchar_format  ( to_date(cwd, 'YYMMDDHH24MISS')         
                    , 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' ) as vc_from_ts
from d                                                       
; -- output from above query follows, as likeness of a report:
....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....
VC_INPUT              TS_FROM_VC                  VC_FROM_TS         
121226145503+0530     2012-12-26-14.55.03.000000  2012/12/26 14:55:03
********  End of data  ********
```