# DB2 - Argument 02 of function TRANSLATE not valid

Tags: date, db2, ibm-midrange, translate, db2-400

I am having some issues converting a string (yyyymmddhhiiss) to a date using TRANSLATE.

If I use a string directly then it works perfectly fine, but when i use a field of exactly same datatype, varchar(14), then it throws the error from the title.

Here is a basic example of what i am trying to do:

```
WITH test_table AS (
    SELECT '20160101123059' AS d FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
SELECT d
       , translate('ABCD-EF-GH IJ:KL:MN', d, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN')
       , translate('ABCD-EF-GH IJ:KL:MN', '20160101123059','ABCDEFGHIJKLMN')
  FROM test_table
```

Can one of you explain why this is not working? Thanks.

Comment: That of course is not _converting a string (yyyymmddhhiiss) to a date_, but instead reformatting a string [of digits] into a string formatted like a timestamp [which includes both a date and a time]. If the effect should be a TIMESTAMP data-type, then see the comment re "using TIMESTAMP() directly".  Otherwise:
Re the comment about how the goal was achieved using substring, the expression was not shown, though whatever was used, there are likely simpler means; e.g. two nearly identical variations: 
 `VARCHAR_FORMAT(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')`
 `TO_CHAR(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the DB2 for i manual...

> to-string
>   A string that specifies the characters to which certain
>   characters in expression are to be converted. This string is sometimes
>   called the output translation table. The string must be any built-in
>   numeric or string **constant**.

So it won't work the way you're trying to use it.

Argument 2 must be a constant value.

Assuming a supported release of the IBM i, you should be able to use the `timestamp()` function to convert the 14-character string directly to timestamp.

```
select timestamp('20160101123059')
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I ended up formatting it manually with SUBSTR.

Comment: @okdios, see the addition to my answer about using `TIMESTAMP()` directly

Answer (score 1):

You cas use :
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('20160101123059' , 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')

If you want a char to result:
cast(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('20160101123059' , 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as varchar(50))